# How to use ls -i on a different directory to get inodes of subdirectories matching a specific pattern?

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to create a command that takes 3 args (directory to search in, pattern to match, and then file to create where data is written) but am a bit stuck because I can't figure out how to get inodes to show for these search results as well to be written in the file. It would be something like:

```
for i in "directory" if name = "pattern", inodes > "file"
```

like it should be simple and yet I cannot seem to get it?  Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't show inodes (ls -i tends to show all subdirectories regardless of pattern match) and says my 3rd argument is too ambiguous...

```
#!/bin/bash

find "$1" -name "*$2*" > "$3"
```

I am wondering if I should be using something like `ls /$directory -i` but I feel like the syntax would not work.

Comment: If using GNU find, `find "$1" -name "$2" -printf "%i\n" > "$3"`

Answer (score 2):

You're close. You've got the searching part down. The missing piece is how to execute `ls -i` on the matching files. To do that, use `-exec <command>`, like so:

```
find "$1" -name "*$2*" -exec ls -i {} + > "$3"
```

The general syntax here is `-exec <command> +`, which executes *command* on all of the files that have been matched.

- The `{}` curly braces at the end of the command are a placeholder. They tell `-exec` where in the command line to substitute the names of the matched files.
- `+` is a marker for the end of the `-exec` action. Every `-exec` action must end with either `+` or `';'`. `+` means "pass all of the files to a single invocation of *command*" and `';'` means "call *command* multiple times, once per file".
- If you use `+` then the curly braces have to be at the very end. The file names are all *concatenated* to the command. With `';'` the `{}` can be anywhere, not just the end.

You might also want to use `ls -id`. By default `ls` will list the contents of directories. The `-d` flag tells it to list the directories themselves rather than what's inside them.

Comment: thank you for the concise explanation! it's a big help

Comment: You should accept the answer (check mark on the left of the answer).